Fix the distance restraint between two set of molecules in gromacs
it seems that in GROMACS we can apply distance restraint between two atoms/particles. However, does anyone know if one can apply a distance restraint between whole two set of molecules, like apply a distance restraint between the COM/COG of one set of molecule with another. Looking forward to any suggestions/advice if anyone has implemented this procedure before. Thanks.

I'm pretty sure you can hack this using the pull code. In case you cant, you can use [intermolecular_interactions], although this will be more laborious.
